# Excel COM with C++: How to check if RangeFromPoint returns a range or a shape object

Tags: excel, com, c++17

I would like to convert the following code from VBA to C++. I get the Excel COM API by using import directives.

VBA:

```
Dim objRFP As Object

Set objRFP = ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(X:=75, Y:=250)

If Not objRFP Is Nothing Then
    If TypeOf objRFP Is Excel.Range Then
        'do something
    Else
        'Shape object, do something else
    End If
End If
```

C++:

```
std::any pXlRFP = pXlApp->ActiveWindow->RangeFromPoint(75, 250);

if (&pXlRFP) {
  if (pXlRFP.type() == typeid(Excel::RangePtr)) { // This doesn't work!!!
    // do something
  }
  else {
    // Shape object; do something else
  }
}
```

How can I check if pXlRFP points to a range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COM only deals with interfaces. To check if a COM pointer supports a particular interface, [call `QueryInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/queryinterface?view=msvc-170) with the appropriate IID.

Depending on what smart pointer library you are using, there is likely an efficient way to do this. Make sure to `Release` the interface acquired if you are not using smart pointers and QI succeeds.

Assuming you are using MSVC `#import` (and therefore `_com_ptr`), that would look something like:

```
IDispatchPtr pUnk = pWindow->RangeFromPoint(250, 250);

Excel::RangePtr pRange;
if (!pUnk) 
{
    // pUnk is empty
    MessageBox(0, L"Empty", L"RangeFromPoint", 0);
}
else if (pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRange)) == S_OK)
{
    // pRange refers to a Range now
    _bstr_t addy = pRange->GetAddress(_variant_t(VARIANT_FALSE), _variant_t(VARIANT_FALSE), Excel::xlA1);
    MessageBox(0, addy, L"RangeFromPoint", 0);
}
else 
{
    // pUnk is something else
    MessageBox(0, L"Some other type", L"RangeFromPoint", 0);
}
```

[Full sample gist](https://gist.github.com/mgaffigan/b49290e2a88524e620164f270711d91a) (elides error checking and message loop).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you give me a quick example of how I can apply this?

Comment: @Armin_K, I added an example calling QI.  You may want to spend some time reading about COM and `IDispatch` basics; it is easy to end up with a leak or a crash.  `AddRef`/`Release`/`QueryInterface` are key to understand and easy to misuse - though smart pointers and the generated `IDispatch` clients do make things easier.

Comment: thank you very much! The example is really helpful.